# Cannot send mail using Zend library

Tags: php, zend-framework, email

**require_once** does not seem to work. I am trying to use Zend libraries to send mail but something does not work. I am using my web hosting server provider so I have to put the libraries in a subdirectory (without installing any framework).

```
// $path= dirname(__FILE__)."/ZendLibrary:".get_include_path() ;
$path= "./ZendLibrary".PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path() ;
set_include_path($path);
//echo $path ;

echo "Spot 0" ;
require_once 'Zend/Mail.php';
echo "Spot 1" ;
```

I **got the "Spot 0"** message but **I don't get the "Spot 1"** message. I have selected only two Zend libraries:

```
 ZendLibrary/Zend/Mail/* (directory)
 ZendLibrary/Zend/Mime/* (directory)
 ZendLibrary/Zend/Mail.php (script)
 ZendLibrary/Zend/Mime.php (script)
```

ZendLibrary is a folder in the same directory where my script is. What could happening?

**UPDATE#1:**

My problem is that the code stops working right when I run **require_once**. It does not echo "Spot 1" message. I have tried absolute paths for **set_include_path**, I have tried to load a .php library script without internal require_once statements, but nothing makes it work. As my test is run from a web hosting site in the Internet I don't have access to logs!.. or do I?

```
$path= realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/ZendLibrary').PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path() ;
// $path= "./ZendLibrary".PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path() ;
set_include_path($path);
```

Comment: just check the path for your Zend library and here are the dependencies. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/requirements.introduction.html. Also in the development environment activate the error_reporting so you can get helpful errors.

Comment: I do not have any development environment at home. I am using a subdirectory at my web hoster to test. Is there any way to see any error some where in my web host server? So far I had to look and look to gues what is wrong.

Comment: I also suspect the path was/is not right and I have concentrated my efforts on that to no avail.

Comment: you need to persevere. The path issues are tricky but once solved your application will go smooth. Try to active the error reporting. Your approach with get_include_path and __FILE__ is correct. Check separately each one of these and maybe try an absolute path for the library at least at the beginning.

Comment: See my answer below, and you can download [this file](https://revival.itsmyns.com/downloads/ZendMail.zip) and see if it works for you.  It is a working example of Zend_mail Standalone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**

My ISP (web hosting too) has a setting to disable **require_once**. I was able to setup a Unbuntu virtual machine on VirtualBox and set up a web server. I copied the content of my test web site in my Unbuntu and find out that require_once does work as expected !!! That may explain why the server-side include did not work for me either. The following was a usefull check, that indicated me the file was in the expected place.

```
$file = 'ZendLibrary/Zend/Mail.php'; 

if ((!is_file($file)) or (!is_readable($file))) 
   die("File does not exists or is not readable.");
```

Now I have to find out why it is disabled, how to enable it, or just switch web hosting company. **Update:** I had to pay $20 dolars a year more for the provider to enable PHP (in this case to be able to include).

[This site](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=2973) can tell you more about it.

Answer (score 1):

Zend Mail has some [dependencies](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/requirements.introduction.html).
Hard dependencies

1. Zend_Exception
2. Zend_Loader
3. Zend_Mime
4. Zend_Validate

Soft

- Zend_Locale
- Zend_Date
- Zend_Filter
- Zend_Registry

The best is to [add all Zend library to the include path](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/performance.classloading.html) in PHP and all components will load the dependencies automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You havent met all the dependencies... At the minimum you also need `Zend_Exception` (all component specific exceptions in the framework extend form this) but im pretty sure there are others that `Mail` and `Mime` depend on. Just to make it easy on myself i would also grab `Zend/Loader` and use it for autoloading.

**Update**:

I took a look and it seems as though you will also need `Zend/Validate` and `Zend/Loader` which is required by one of the classes in `Validate` component - though Mail only uses `Zend/Validate/Hostname` (which does depend on the abstract classes and interfaces for Validate as well as `Zend_Validate_Ip`) so you might be able to get away with not grabbing `Zend/Loader`, but you might as well jsut make use of it for general purpose autoloading.

As a suggestion you could use `[Swift Mailer`][1](http://swiftmailer.org/) instead... youll be bale to avoid dependency hell and i like it a lot better anyhow. Only down side is its for Sending mail, while `Zend_Mail` will also let you read a mail store on a local or remote server.

Comment: there is no more dependency hell, the solution is called autoloading http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/performance.classloading.html

Comment: I have to first find a way for the "require_once" to work; or ... is it that I need to run "require_once 'Zend/Validate.php';" for the "require_once 'Zend/Mail.php';" to work?;

Comment: If you arent going to use the `Zend_Loader` then you need to require all the dependencies manually.

Answer (score 0):

I used Zend_Mail with SMTP standalone before, here are the files I needed.  I also reduced it down to what you need if you only want to use sendmail also.

If you want to use Sendmail, that is the easiest.  Your dependencies are:

- Zend/Exception.php
- Zend/Mail.php
- Zend/Mime.php
- Zend/Mail/Exception.php
- Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php
- Zend/Mail/Transport/Exception.php
- Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php
- Zend/Mime/Exception.php
- Zend/Mime/Message.php
- Zend/Mime/Part.php

And with those files, here is an example use:

```
<?php
// optionally
// set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/path/to/Zend');

require_once 'Zend/Mail.php';
require_once 'Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php';

$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail();

$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->addTo('user@domain')
     ->setSubject('Mail Test')
     ->setBodyText("Hello,\nThis is a Zend Mail message...\n")
     ->setFrom('sender@domain');

try {
    $mail->send($transport);
    echo "Message sent!<br />\n";
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo "Failed to send mail! " . $ex->getMessage() . "<br />\n";
}
```

If you need SMTP, then you have a few more dependencies as prodigitalson showed.  In addition to the above you need at least:

- Zend/Loader.php
- Zend/Registry.php
- Zend/Validate.php
- Zend/Mail/Protocol/Abstract.php
- Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php
- Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php
- Zend/Validate/Abstract.php
- Zend/Validate/Hostname.php
- Zend/Validate/Interface.php
- Zend/Validate/Ip.php
- Zend/Validate/Hostname/*
- Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp/Auth/*

Then you can do something like this:

```
<?php

require_once 'Zend/Mail.php';
require_once 'Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php';

$config    = array(//'ssl' => 'tls',
                   'port' => '25', //465',
                   'auth' => 'login',
                   'username' => 'user',
                   'password' => 'password');

$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.example.com', $config);

$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->addTo('user@domain')
     ->setSubject('Mail Test')
     ->setBodyText("Hello,\nThis is a Zend Mail message...\n")
     ->setFrom('sender@domain');

try {
    $mail->send($transport);
    echo "Message sent!<br />\n";
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo "Failed to send mail! " . $ex->getMessage() . "<br />\n";
}
```